# How to solve for n on top of the sigma sign in a sum?

Tags: algorithms

Say that I have an equation:

$$\displaystyle  \sum^n_{t=1}{E_tR_t} = A$$

The t here represents the value of E/R (simple numbers that are different at every timestep t) at timestep t and A represents the value that multiplying a bunch of E's and R's and then summing them all has to add up to.

What I want to know is how to find how many timesteps t does it take until I get to A (rounded up to the nearest integer), in other words I want to solve for n.

$$E_t$$ and $$R_t$$

are given at each timestep t, but are different at every timestep t. A is simply a number that I want to reach. How to solve this?

Comment: With arbitrary E and R, I don't see how you can approach this any other way than just computing A for each choice of n. Without any information about E or R, value A could literally be anything at any time step, so I don't see any way to tell what n gets you to a specific value of A.

Comment: Well we have all the information about E and R, we know their value at each timestep. For example at day 1  E is 0.8 and R 30, at day 2 E is 0.6 and R is 40, so on..

Comment: Can $E_t$ and $R_t$ be expressed as simple functions of the timestep number $t$? If so, maybe you can then find an explicit form of the sum in terms of $n$, and then maybe you can solve for $n$ directly.

Comment: No, E_t and R_t are basically experimental data, or rather a plan of the future. The situation I am imagining is one where I have, say, 100 days worth of E_t and R_t values, that is to say, I know what the E_t and R_t will be at each timestep(day) for 100 timesteps. Then I know that by adding up multiples of E_t and R_t every day I need to reach some amount, for example 1000. What I want to find is how many days, based on the list of future E_t's and R_t's it will take me to get to my goal of 1000.

Comment: @Rico Unless E and R are functions of t, there's no way to solve it analytically - you just need to compute A at every timestep, and see when you're done. Set n=1, and compute A. If you've reached your target, you're done. If not, increment n, and repeat. You just need to keep trying n's until you find one that works, as there's no way to guess what A will be at time t without actually looking at all the data up through time t.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and also explains why I couldn't figure it out after an hour of trying haha. I will approach this algorithmically then. I suppose this also means that there is no great way to express this in mathematical symbolism?